# Fatal error - Login_Plugin_SecurityCheck not found

Tags: php, zend-auth

I am trying to implement user login using PHP/Zend. Following the example below:
https://github.com/ezimuel/Authentication-and-authorization-with-ZF.git

I get the following errors when going to http://localhost/

> Warning: include_once(Login/Plugin/SecurityCheck.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Library/WebServer/Documents/xxxxx/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 146
>
> Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Login/Plugin/SecurityCheck.php' for inclusion (include_path='/Library/WebServer/Documents/xxxxx/application/../library:/Library/WebServer/Documents/xxxxx/library:/Library/WebServer/Documents/xxxxx/application/modules/login/library:.:/usr/lib/php') in /Library/WebServer/Documents/xxxxx/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 146
>
> Fatal error: Class 'Login_Plugin_SecurityCheck' not found in /Library/WebServer/Documents/xxxxx/library/Zend/Application/Resource/Frontcontroller.php on line 117

I setup the project by following the Zend Quickstart Tutorials, so my application.ini file is slightly different. Im guessing this is a simple case of the application not being able to find certain files?

Answer (score 0):

Have you got these lines in your `application.ini`:

```
resources.frontController.defaultModule = "login"
resources.frontController.params.prefixDefaultModule = "1"
resources.modules[]=
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.plugins[] = "Login_Plugin_SecurityCheck"
```

Also, I notice the plugin is specified in the config as `Login_Plugin_SecurityCheck`, but in the login module, the folder is `plugins`, not `plugin`.

Comment: Yes. Here is the production section of my .ini file. Just out of interest, should these also be in my development section?

[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
resources.view[] =

Comment: resources.db.adapter = "PDO_SQLITE"
    resources.db.params.dbname = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/db/xxxxx.db"

    autoloaderNamespaces[] ="Login_"
    resources.frontController.defaultModule = "login"
    resources.frontController.params.prefixDefaultModule = "1"
    resources.modules[]=
    resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
    resources.frontController.plugins[] = "Login_Plugin_SecurityCheck"

Comment: Ok, try changing the folder `plugins` to `plugin` in `application / modules / login / `

Comment: I renamed /application/modules/login/plugins to /application/modules/login/plugin but i get the same error. Guessing it is having trouble finding the SecurityCheck.php file? Does it matter that i am not calling the bootstrap in /application/modules/login/bootstrap.php?

Comment: Having a little more detailed look at your error, it looks like the `modules/` folder isn't being checked by your autoloader. [This page](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html) may help you to add it - I'm not sure what might be the best way.

Comment: Still not managed to work it out but thanks for your help Chris!

Comment: Ok - change the `plugin` folder back to `plugin`, and if you put this in your Bootstrap, it should work. `ini_set('include_path', ini_get('include_path') . ";".APPLICATION_PATH.'/modules');` I'm not sure though what the best ZF way of doing this would be.

Comment: plugin back to plugins? I have a bootstrap in /application and also one in /application/modules/login - should i put it in the /application/bootstrap.php ?

My application.ini has the following:
    bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
    bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"