# PHP / Zend - can not find SecurityCheck.php file

Tags: php, zend-auth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fatal error - Login_Plugin_SecurityCheck not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176301/fatal-error-login-plugin-securitycheck-not-found)

I am trying to implement a login for my application, using the following example: [Authentication-and-authorization-with-ZF](https://github.com/ezimuel/Authentication-and-authorization-with-ZF).
It seems my application is not referencing the location of the SecurityCheck.php file, which is located /application/modules/login/plugins/SecurityCheck.php

I get the following error message:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Login_Plugins_SecurityCheck' not found in  /Library/WebServer/Documents/myProjectName/library/Zend/Application/Resource/Frontcontroller.php on line 117
```

This is what my application.ini file looks like:

```
resources.frontController.defaultModule = "login"
resources.frontController.params.prefixDefaultModule = "1"
resources.modules[]=
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.plugins[] = "Login_Plugins_SecurityCheck"
```

Any ideas where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try resources.frontController.plugins.securityCheck = "Login_Plugins_SecurityCheck" instead of  resources.frontController.plugins[] = ...

Comment: Tried it.. but it didn't work :(

Comment: My SecurityCheck.php file starts with the following..

    class Login_Plugin_SecurityCheck extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract

Should that be:

    class Login_Plugins_SecurityCheck extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract

..instead? Although it doesn't work either

Comment: have you got this in your config. 
appnamespace= "Login"
autoloaderNamespaces[] ="Login_".

The example you are looking at seems to have a really strange setup. With a app namespace of Login and a module of Login, I would expect the class to be called Login_Login_Plugin_SecurityCheck

Comment: I have got appnamespace="Login_" - as it shows here - https://github.com/ezimuel/Authentication-and-authorization-with-ZF/blob/master/application/configs/application.ini

I also get the following errors:
Warning: include_once(Login/Plugin/SecurityCheck.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Library/WebServer/Documents/myProject/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 146

Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Login/Plugin/SecurityCheck.php' for inclusion (include_path='/Library/WebServer/Documents/myProject/application/../library:/Lib..

Comment: Try calling the class Login_Login_Plugin_SecurityCheck? Does that help?

Comment: I tried that already with no luck.